# Why Object.getPrototypeOf() and constructor.prototype logs different values

Tags: javascript, prototype

In following code, using getPrototypeOf() and constructor.prototype gives different values.

```
function C(){ }
function D(){ }

C.prototype.fname = "John";  

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(C)); //function () {}
console.log(C.prototype); // C{fname: "John"}
```

Comment: did the explanation help you?

Answer (score 3):

That is because [Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) returns the prototype inherited from its parent constructor.

```
function C(){ }
```

Now this is constructed by primitive type `Function`

Hence when you call `getPrototypeOf` on `C` `__Proto__` lookup from inherited parent constructor is returned(Read this [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)).

**See the below for illustration:** See the inline comments for understanding

```
typeof C // "function"
C instanceof Function // True
Object.getPrototypeOf(C) === Function.constructor.prototype // "True"
Function.constructor.prototype // "function(){}"
Object.getPrototypeOf(C) // "function(){}"
```

**Now the next part:**

```
C.prototype.fname = "John";
typeof C.prototype // object
```

Hence its constructor becomes `C()` with prototype object chain inherited from `C()` which will be inherited when you create instance like this `new C()`

**Hence:**

```
C.prototype.constructor // "function C(){}" -- Parent constructor
```

So when you lookup `Prototype` on `C()` it returns the `prototype` inherited from its contructor like below

```
C.prototype.constructor === C //true
C.prototype === C.prototype.constructor.prototype // True
C.prototype.constructor.prototype // C {fname: "John"}
C.prototype // C {fname: "John"}
```

**Conclusion:**

When ever you search for a prototype on a Object or Function lookup happens on the properties inherited from its parent constructor.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(C) === C.constructor.prototype //true
Object.getPrototypeOf(C) === Function.prototype // true
C.prototype === (new C()).__proto__ // true (this is for illustration only dont use __proto__ in your code)
```

> `Object.getPrototypeOf(C)` is not equal to `C.prototype` because their
>   constructors are different.

---

***References:***

- https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(C));
```

This returns the prototype of the class C rather than an instance of C. These should return the same result:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new C()));
console.log(C.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.getPrototypeOf(C);` is basically doing the same thing that `C.__proto__` does, which is it

> "Points to the object which was used as prototype when the object was instantiated."

When `C()` was instantiated, it was a function. Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

And part of the description of Object.prototype from MDN:

> "All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they may be overridden (except an Object with a null prototype, i.e. Object.create(null))."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Meaning `C.prototype` is just pointing to the object that contains the methods and properties an object instantiated from it will inherit (or in this case it was overridden to a string), while `Object.getPrototypeOf(C)`is looking at the initial object that was used to create `C` a.k.a. `C.__proto__`.

Comment: Can this be rephrased as "when `C()` was instantiated, it was a function." - - when `C()` was instantiated, it was instantiated using a function viz `function() {}`.

Comment: When you first created `C`, you created it as a function. `function C(){}`

Comment: You say "Meaning C.prototype is just pointing to the object that contains the methods and properties it inherits from". In my opinion `C` does not inherit from 'C.prototype` rather it's instantiated objects say `var Obj = new C()`  that inherits properties and methods from `C.prototype`.

Comment: You're right, I made an edit to try to convey that a little better.